# SQL Quotes a produce sql syntax error on one server, not another

Tags: php, mysql, quotes

Strange one here, I moved a site and database from one LAMP server to another. On the old server users can enter text into text areas that include quotes with no problem. I'm assuming it's either in the php or sql configuration files, the trouble is, my host on the old site won't provide those files so I'm not sure what to change. Any ideas why it works on one but not the other?

Here's the line of code just in case:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Stu SET Stu_IDD = '$snumd', First = '$first', Last = '$last', 
             MPhone = '$mphone', HPhone = '$hphone',  EContact = '$econtact', 
             EPhone = '$ephone', GMail = '$gmail', PMail = '$pmail', 
             Address = '$address', Apt = '$apt', Pcode = '$pcode', 
             City = '$city', DOB = '$dob', Gender = '$gender', 
             Deaf = '$deaf', Notes = '$notes' 
             WHERE Stu_ID = '$snum'") 
      or die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks so much in advance for your time and replies!

Comment: 1) What is the text of the syntax error?  2) You might want to parametrize this query as you might be leaving yourself open to a sql injection attack.

Answer (score 1):

> On the old server users can enter text into text areas that include
>   quotes with no problem.

It looks like your quotes got escaped automatically on the old server, probably because of a setting in old php versions called [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

This "feature" has been deprecated and removed and should not be relied on anyway to escape data for a database.

You should switch to PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements with bound parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to not allow unescaped quotes in your db for security reasons anyway. Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to escape these characters: `\x00, \n, \r, \, ', ", \x1a`

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score -1):

Within new versions of mysql, the query commands use mysqli instead of mysql... Try doing mysqli_query instead. If this doesn't work, make sure the names of the database and the ones in the query match.